# How to Animate Text from a Shake Event

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sensors, android-sensors

I currently have an app that allows the user to shake the phone and different texts appear from an array. However, the text keeps displaying too fast, and if the user keeps shaking the phone, the text keeps changing. How do i do the following:

1) Animate the text so after the phone is shaken, the text appears slowly as a fade?

2. How do I implement a delay on the shake so that the user has a wait a few seconds before shaking the phone?

I have already implemented this for a button that is clicked, however nothing seems to work with Sensor Manager.

```
protected final SensorEventListener sensorListener = new SensorEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {


            float x = sensorEvent.values[0];
            float y = sensorEvent.values[1];
            float z = sensorEvent.values[2];

            acelLast = acelVal;
            acelVal = (float) Math.sqrt((double) (x*x + y*y + z*z));
            float delta = acelVal - acelLast;
            shake = shake * 0.9f + delta;

            if (shake > 12) {

                int randomNum = new Random().nextInt(answersArray.length);
                ball_text.setText(answersArray[randomNum]);
                ball_text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


            }





        }



        @Override
        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

        }
    };

    // Sensor Section //
```

Comment: 1 - You can use `AlphaAnimation` to change `TextView` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AlphaAnimation 
2 - You can apply `debounce` operation to shake event. For example you shown "Text1" and don't update next text if 2 seconds did not pass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You'll need to animate your textview's alpha value change.
2. You'll need to keep track of the last time the user shaked and use that for checking.

Something along the following lines should work,

```
long previousTime = 0;

protected final SensorEventListener sensorListener = new SensorEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
            float x = sensorEvent.values[0];
            float y = sensorEvent.values[1];
            float z = sensorEvent.values[2];

            acelLast = acelVal;
            acelVal = (float) Math.sqrt((double) (x*x + y*y + z*z));
            float delta = acelVal - acelLast;
            shake = shake * 0.9f + delta;

            if (shake > 12) {
              //Fade in text if difference between previous and current time is > 2 seconds
              if (System.currentTimeMillis() - previousTime > 2000) {
                previousTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                //Use AlphaAnimation
                Animation fadeInAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(0, 1);
                fadeInAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                        int randomNum = new Random().nextInt(answersArray.length);
                        ball_text.setText(answersArray[randomNum]);
                        ball_text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {}
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
                });
                fadeInAnimation.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
                fadeInAnimation.setDuration(1000);
                ball_text.startAnimation(fadeInAnimation);
                /*
                //This should work, but it doesn't, I'll prob tinker with it on some weekend, I'll update the answer if I figure out the issue
                ball_text.animate()
                   .withStartAction(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                int randomNum = new Random().nextInt(answersArray.length);
                                ball_text.setText(answersArray[randomNum]);
                                ball_text.setAlpha(0f);
                                ball_text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }
                        })
                   .alpha(1f)
                   //Fade in over a duration of 1 second
                   .setDuration(1000)
                   .start()

                */
              } else {
                //If it's less than 2 seconds since last shake, inform user to wait
                //For eg,
                Toast.makeText(context, "Wait mate", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        }
    };
```

Comment: Thank you! This works almost perfectly. The fade from the shake is still not fading. It just appears quickly. If you know anyway to slow this down, please let me know. Thanks again.

Comment: Did you try increasing the `setDuration` value, something like `setDuration(3000)` maybe?

Comment: Yeah- I tried that, still nothing happened. I tried 5000 too haha Thank you.

Comment: That's weird, I've used something along this line before, but it doesn't work right now. 

Comment: I've updated my answer to use `AlphaAnimation`, I don't particularly like it since it's more verbose. But it works. Mark my answer as correct and upvote if it works. Cheers.

Comment: Also, how can mark the answer as correct and upvote it? Im not seeing that on my page. I'm new to this site.

Comment: Glad it worked, there should be a grey up arrow and tick mark to the left of my answer.

Comment: Actually, I don't think you can upvote until you have 15 reputation. But you should be able to click on the Grey tick mark to choose the answer as correct. Cheers.